# Access Kubernetes service (in Vagrant) on localhost

Tags: vagrant, kubernetes, vagrantfile

I have created a service on some pods in Kubernetes. I'm able to curl the service-ip:port and I see some HTML. 
I want to access the service in my browser on my own PC.
What do I have to edit in my Vagrantfile to map my vagrant internal IP on my localhost (of PC)?
This is a part of my vagrantfile (I think the part where I have to make edits)

```
    # Finally, fall back to VirtualBox
    config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |v, override|
      setvmboxandurl(override, :virtualbox)
      v.memory = vm_mem # v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", vm_mem]
      v.cpus = $vm_cpus # v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpus", $vm_cpus]

      # Use faster paravirtualized networking
      v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--nictype1", "virtio"]
      v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--nictype2", "virtio"]
    end
  end

  # Kubernetes master
  config.vm.define "master" do |c|
    customize_vm c, $vm_master_mem
    if ENV['KUBE_TEMP'] then
      script = "#{ENV['KUBE_TEMP']}/master-start.sh"
      c.vm.provision "shell", run: "always", path: script
    end
    c.vm.network "private_network", ip: "#{$master_ip}"
  end

  # Kubernetes node
  $num_node.times do |n|
    node_vm_name = "node-#{n+1}"
    node_prefix = ENV['INSTANCE_PREFIX'] || 'kubernetes' # must mirror default in cluster/vagrant/config-default.sh
    node_hostname = "#{node_prefix}-#{node_vm_name}"

    config.vm.define node_vm_name do |node|
      customize_vm node, $vm_node_mem

      node_ip = $node_ips[n]
      if ENV['KUBE_TEMP'] then
        script = "#{ENV['KUBE_TEMP']}/node-start-#{n}.sh"
        node.vm.provision "shell", run: "always", path: script
      end
      node.vm.network "private_network", ip: "#{node_ip}"
    end
  end
```

I tried to change `node.vm.network "private_network", ip: "#{node_ip}"` in `node.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.xx.xx.xx"`but I'm not able to reload my vagrant:

```
/opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/ipaddr.rb:559:in `in6_addr': invalid address (IPAddr::InvalidAddressError)
```

Comment: can you add `p node_ip` after `node_ip = $node_ips[n]` to check the value - can't guess what is the value from `node_ips` but it complains its not a valid IP address, check the value

Comment: $node_ips = $num_node.times.collect { |n| $node_ip_base + "#{n+3}" } is in the file. But I just tried to change "#{node_ip}" to "192..." (hardcoded). And it's complaining? here https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/private_network.html they seem to do the same?

Comment: well the error happens when you really have an error in your IP. something like `192.168.32.310` (out of range) or `192.168.01.12` ; can you use `192.168.33.10` as an example of a valid IP and check if it still does not work

Comment: I got the same issue with the IP between the range. I just edit the line I described above and "vagrant reload"

Comment: I even took a backup of my original vagrantfile and restored it and still the same issue..

Comment: its the same for `master_ip` ? and other network IP you could have in your file ; just try  to replace all with valid IP - there must be one that is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

Your service needs to be of type NodePort to be reached on the IP of the vagrant VM. For example if your pods are started by a replication controller. Create the services with:

`kubectl expose rc foobar --type=NodePort --port=80`

This will return a random port. Open your browser on your Vagrant node VM at that port and you will reach your service.

Comment: At the moment I'm doing this: --port=80 --target-port=8080 So the port 8080 of my pod (container) on 80 of my service. So I also have to define NodePort which will map this to a random port on the IP of my vagrant VM?